# SetImageList in CMFCToolBar

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm updating my programm from CToolBar to CMFCToolBar and have this code:

```
void CMainFrame::createToolBarEx(CToolBar& toolBar, int nId, int nStyle, 
                             CImageList& imList, 
                             CImageList& imListD,
                             CImageList& imListH)
{
if (!toolBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT, nStyle) ||
    !toolBar.LoadToolBar(nId))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create toolbar\n");
}
toolBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_TOP);


toolBar.GetToolBarCtrl().SetImageList(&imList);
toolBar.GetToolBarCtrl().SetDisabledImageList(&imListD);
toolBar.GetToolBarCtrl().SetHotImageList(&imListH);
```

}

But there aren't such functions (SetImageList ,SetDisabledImageList ,SetHotImageList) in CMFCToolBar. So what should I use to have the same result? Maybe AddToolBarForImageCollection or CMFCToolBarButton? If I'm wright, how should I use them? Can you give some examples?

Comment: Yes, `AddToolBarForImageCollection`. You don't need to create the ImageLIst anymore, just give it the resource ID of the bitmaps containing your images. The Feature Pack ships with documentation; have you consulted it?

Comment: @CodyGray This documentation doesn't answer my questions. 
At first , I have several toolbars, and when I use AddToolBarForImageCollection it change them all, however I need different bitmaps for different toolbars. Secondly, this function change only"cold" and "disable" image , while "hot" images present as in toolbar - (LoadToolBar(nId)). So what I should do?

Comment: Hmm, information like that ("I have several toolbars...and need different bitmaps for different toolbars") should have been in the question. Anyway, I looked in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983344.aspx), and it says that `AddToolBarForImageCollection` actually just creates a temporary toolbar by calling `LoadToolbar`. So then I looked at [the documentation for `LoadToolbar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983090.aspx). Seems like that is what you want, it has a parameter for a "hot" image bitmap, too. Are you using it already?

Comment: @CodyGray Ooo, I missed it. It works, as I need! Thank you!